# Writing an Rspec test for `User#index`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have been testing an API using Rspec and FactoryGirl. I am trying to test `User#index`, which is meant to render a JSON response containing all `User`s. How can I create an array of `FactoryGirl` Users and see if the JSON response corresponds to it? In the `user_controller_spec`, I am testing the `GET #index` method. Is that the correct method to test for `User#index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory girl comes with built in helper functions to assist in creating an array of objects.
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#building-or-creating-multiple-records

For your controller test you can follow these examples pretty easily for testing your index. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

As a side note, I just got out of Rails Conf in KC a week ago. 1 of the talks discussed how controller tests are not worth while but instead suggested a combination of simple unit tests combined with full request tests (which covers your controller). Just something to think about. Best of Luck!